# Auto show/expand outliner to selected objects

Tags: outliner

I'm not sure if it's possible, but if it is that would be great!

Is there a way to make it so when I select an object in the scene, the outliner will automatically expand the hierarchy to show the selected object?

Comment: Hello :). Not to my knowledge, but you can just press `Numpad ,` with cursor over outliner

Answer (score 3):

So we know that if the object is already visible in the outliner (not buried in a hierarchy like bones), it will be "highlighted", but the outliner will not auto-scroll to display it.

If you hover your mouse over the outliner window and enter '.', it will scroll and expand hierarchy to display the selected object.

Sometimes I set up another copy of the outliner, and in the filters select to show "Selected" Objects, instead of the default "All".  However, if I selected a hierarchical child object (like a bone), it will still not cooperate fully unless I enter '.' (will then expand to the selected child).

Note that Shift-"right arrow" will expand the complete child hierarchy from the selected parent.

[image]

For those of us 3ds Max converts, blender disappoints here.  I may update if I come up with a python script to "sync outliner to selection" in the 3ds Max way.